# PHP variable name conflict with session variables

Tags: php, session, variables, namespaces

I have the following segment of code that someone else has written, and that I'm trying to fix:

```
function calc() {
    require_once("db.php");     
    connect();

    $a = split("#", $_SESSION['freight']);
    $loc = $a[0];

    $r = mysql_query("SELECT `price`, `gst` FROM `freight` WHERE `location`='$loc'");
    $arr = mysql_fetch_array($r);
    $_SESSION['freight'] = $loc."#".$arr['price'];      

    return $arr['price'];
}

function ajaxFunction () {
    $_SESSION['freight'] = $_GET['loc']; 
    $freight = calc();
    echo number_format($freight, 2);
    return;
}
```

It ain't pretty, I am just trying to fix it.

Now I have noticed the bug seems to stem from the fact $freight = calc(). After that line, $freight will equal say $10 (the $arr['price'] value). **BUT** the $_SESSION['freight'] will also equal $10, and just $10, as if it was the same variable as $freight. What ever I set $freight to, the $_SESSION['freight'] also becomes.

If I change $freight in the ajax function to $freight2 it doesn't alter the session variable. Is this something major that I don't know about PHP? That variable names share the same namespace as session variables?

The question overall is:
Does changing $a alter $_SESSION['a'] in anyway? Because it really seems like it does.

Comment: the last vakue of `$_SESSION['freight']` is `$loc."#".$arr['price'];`

Comment: How did you determine the value of the session var is the same? The only way the variable  would get the value of the other would be if it was a reference to it, but at least in the code you show it isn't.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, some sort of reference, but I can't seem to find it. It might be hidden some where else, but I just can't find it after trawling through the code. I know that logically that the above shouldn't happen, and that it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Does your php have `register_globals` turned on? That'd cause any session variables to be auto-linked into real variables of the same name. If this is turned on, TURN IT OFF.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your register globals is set to on in your php.ini file. You need to turn that off. If it's on, your $_SESSION, $_GET, $_POST elements can be referred to as the variable names.

e.g. $_SESSION['item'] is the same as $item

More info here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals

Also, register globals is now deprecated, which also means that if this is indeed the issue, you were using an older version of PHP, and may want to consider upgrading.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I didn't know about this, my other servers must all have this OFF, whereas this particular project that I'm helping does indeed have it ON. I was ripping my hair out trying to understand why, thank you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell...

your `$_SESSION` variable should not be a session variable at all as it always equals `$_SESSION['freight'] = $loc."#".$arr['price'];`

Comment: Yes exactly. I'm happy to set this as correct if there isn't any known way a session variable can share a namespace with a normal variable. If so, I will mark this as an issue with the existing code, and there is some weird variable dependency implemented that I am yet to find

Answer (score 0):

I actually do not understand the use of the session so this is whow i would have approach it

```
function calc($loc) 
{
    require_once("db.php");     
    connect();

    $r = mysql_query("SELECT `price`, `gst` FROM `freight` WHERE `location`='$loc'");

    $arr = mysql_fetch_array($r);

    $_SESSION['freight'] = $loc."#".$arr['price'];      

    return $arr['price'];
}

function ajaxFunction () 
{
    $a = split("#", $_GET['loc']); 
    $freight = calc($a[0]);
    echo number_format($freight, 2);
    return;
}
```

You only need the location so that you can run your queries. So just set the session once with the new data from the database.
Hope that helps

Comment: I couldn't agree more, the problem is the way it has been setup, the session is used elsewhere. I'm not impressed by the above code, but sometime you have to work with what you're given. Otherwise I would take your approach.

Answer (score 0):

I always use different notation for session variables. For example `$_SESSION['_uid']` versus a regular `$uid` variable.

Comment: this is not an answer, explain some more so that user understand it clearly